# confusion with showIntAtBase signature

Tags: haskell

I tried to print a number in binary format, and the function I found is

```
showIntAtBase :: (Integral a, Show a) => a -> (Int -> Char) -> a -> ShowS
```

but I don't understand how it works, especially I don't know what's the purpose of the function parameter converting from `Int` to `Char`. Intuitively, this function should take only 2 parameters, the number to show and a base to show it in, and this seems to be the case in more specific functions from `Numeric`, like

```
showHex :: (Integral a, Show a) => a -> ShowS
```

or

```
showOct :: (Integral a, Show a) => a -> ShowS
```

so what is the purpose of the `(Int -> Char)` parameter in `showIntAtBase`?

Comment: Look at the documentation [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Numeric.html#v:showIntAtBase) which I found [here](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=showintatbase)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Prelude Numeric> putStrLn $ showIntAtBase 10 (\n -> ['0'..'9']!!n) 26734 ""
26734
Prelude Numeric> putStrLn $ showIntAtBase 10 ("⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹"!!) 26734 ""
²⁶⁷³⁴
Prelude Numeric> putStrLn $ showIntAtBase 16 ("0123456789ABCdef"!!) 0xbeef ""
Beef
```

Note that `!!` shouldn't be used for serious applications, it's inefficient. Better use something like

```
Prelude Numeric> let c0 = fromEnum '0' in showIntAtBase 10 (toEnum . (+c0)) 26734 ""
"26734"
```

Comment: `ord` and `chr` seem more appropriate, any point in preferring `fromEnum` / `toEnum` ?

Comment: @pdexter doesn't really matter IMO... they're equivalent anyway, and I think GHC will rewrite them to identical code. I find `ord`/`chr` a bit uselessly specific.